# Cross Compiling Ruby for ARM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arm, cross-compiling

I have cross compiled ruby version - ruby-2.0.0-p481 for ARM.

./configure CC=/opt/atm/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc LDFLAGS=-L/opt/atm/lib/ --prefix=/home/atmuser/upgrade/cortex_ruby1.8.7 --target=armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mthumb' ac_cv_func_getpgrp_void=yes ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=yes --enable-rubygems –with-openssl-dir=/opt/atm/lib/

It is cross-compiled properly and I checked ruby with sample program. It is working fine.

I need to install rails on ARM machine. I am trying "gem install rails" and getting following error.

```
-sh-4.2$ ./gem help install
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- socket
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke' for nil:NilClass
-sh-4.2$ ./gem install rails
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- socket
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
-sh-4.2$
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: What is your machines configuration? Can't you install [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: I need to use ruby on ARMV7 system. I need to cross-compile ruby from source code.